# How can I write encoded hex value in a binary file using python

Tags: python-3.x, hex, binaryfiles

I need to write some random hex value in encoded form in a binary file using python. How can I do that.

For Ex: I need to `write 0x77, 0xff, 0x11 in stack.bin file`, how can I do that using python?

Answer (score 0):

Use **NumPy**

```py
import numpy as np
#Convert your list of numbers to numpy ndarray
numbers = np.array(numbers)

numbers.tofile(filepath)
```

After that you can extract numbers using your *dtype*

```py
numbers = np.fromfile(filepath, dtype=YOUR_DTYPE)
```